# Why readings from .env file are wrong?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I've a problem. I'm new to nodejs so probably it's really easy to fix it. In the main directory, I've a `.env` file. In the main.js file I've:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http')
const {Pool, Client} = require('pg');
require("dotenv").config();
console.log(process.env.USER);
```

So, I simply want to print the `USER` variabile that is located into my `.env` file. Here is my `.env` file:

```
USER=postgres
HOST=localhost
DATABASE=postgres
PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
PORT=5432
```

Anyway, when I write `console.log(process.env.USER);`, the variable printed is not the `USER` variable (that is `postgres`), but my pc user account (that is `John`). How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but have you tried renaming your variables, adding a prefix like `DB_`, so the variables names become `DB_USER`, `DB_HOST` etc.?

Maybe this variable is already taken by the process. And I personally don't like to overwrite them.

You can check running `node` REPL in your terminal, then typing `process.env`.

These are the Node environment variables that are already taken on my PC (running on Windows):

```js
{
  ALLUSERSPROFILE: 'C:\\ProgramData',
  APPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\dizolan\\AppData\\Roaming',
  ChocolateyInstall: 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey',
  CommonProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',
  'CommonProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files',
  CommonProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',
  COMPUTERNAME: '...',
  ComSpec: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe',
  DriverData: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData',
  FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING: 'Internet Explorer',
  FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING: 'Default',
  GOPATH: '...',
  HOMEDRIVE: 'C:',
  HOMEPATH: '...',
  LOCALAPPDATA: '...',
  LOGONSERVER: '...',
  NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: '8',
  OneDrive: '...',
  OS: 'Windows_NT',
  Path: '...',
  PATHEXT: '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW',
  POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL: 'MSI:Windows 10 Pro for Workstations',
  PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: 'AMD64',
  PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel',
  PROCESSOR_LEVEL: '6',
  PROCESSOR_REVISION: '8e0c',
  ProgramData: 'C:\\ProgramData',
  ProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files',
  'ProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)',
  ProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files',
  PSModulePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules',
  PUBLIC: 'C:\\Users\\Public',
  SESSIONNAME: 'Console',
  SystemDrive: 'C:',
  SystemRoot: 'C:\\Windows',
  TEMP: '...',
  TMP: '...',
  USERDNSDOMAIN: '...',
  USERDOMAIN: '...',
  USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: '...',
  USERNAME: '...',
  USERPROFILE: '...',
  windir: 'C:\\Windows'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dotenv` add `override` option at version [14.1.0 (2022-01-17)](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/9a5ec299cf420ada94335d3560bfe1964b4abd97/CHANGELOG.md#1410-2022-01-17) You can use `override: true` option to

> Override any environment variables that have already been set on your machine with values from your `.env` file.

```js
require('dotenv').config({ override: true, debug: true })
console.log(process.env.USER);
```

Output:

```sh
[dotenv][DEBUG] "USER" is already defined in `process.env` and WAS overwritten
postgres
```

`USER` is a system environment variable, see [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)

> USER   The name of the logged-in user (used by some BSD-derived
> programs).  Set at login time, see section NOTES below.